# how to using gtest in OpenMP parallel block?

Tags: openmp, googletest

I want to using gtest in openmp.

I want calculation something in parallel block, and check the thread private variable's result, and do more calculation.

Here is an example.

```
#include "gmock.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace testing;

TEST(SimpleGtest, OpenMP)
{
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        // some thread private variable
        int thread_index = omp_get_thread_num();
        int z;  
        // some calculation
        // ...
        // check result of thread private variable
        ASSERT_THAT(z, Eq(13));
        // other calculation
        // ...
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

but when I compile the code, the compiler complaint that:

```
error: "return" branches to or from an OpenMP structured block are illegal
          ASSERT_THAT(z, Eq(13));
          ^
```

The code above is just a simple example.

I know we can not using "thread private variable" but using "thread shared variable" so we can do the assert out of parallel block.

But is there any solution that we can using gtest to check the thread private variable's result in OpenMP parallel block?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible with OpenMP. You could look at `gtest-parallel` and have different test cases running in parallel at the same time, but that's pretty much it. Can you detail your use-case?

Comment: @AlexG thanks for reply. I try to modify the problem, I just want calculation something in parallel block, and check the thread private variable's result, and do more calculation. thanks for suggsetion of `gtest-parallel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not using `ASSERT_THAT` in parallel block. `EXPECT_EQ` can help.